# Moving absolute div using animation

Tags: jquery

I have an absolute div that I want to move when a right or left arrow is clicked. Everytime the right arrow is clicked, I want to add 323 to the left position and when left arrow is clicked subtract 323 from position. Here's the code I'm using but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#leftArrow a').click(function(){
        $('.image_reel').animate({
            left: '-323px'
        },'fast');
});

$('#rightArrow a').click(function(){
        $('.image_reel').animate({
            left: '323px'
        },'fast');
});
```

Comment: you're always animating to the same position.. don't you want to instead add or subtract to/from the left css property?

Comment: @Kevin B 323px and -323px is not the same position for me

Comment: Right, but it will only animate left once, and right once, rather than right each time he clicks right. jQuery animate (and .css) has the desired functionality built-in, you just have to use it.

Comment: that's what i thought it was, but i tried doing something like  left: -=323 but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just worked for me

```
$('#leftArrow a').click(function(){
    $('.image_reel').animate({
        left: '-=323px'
    },'fast');
});

$('#rightArrow a').click(function(){
    $('.image_reel').animate({
        left: '+=323px'
    },'fast');
});
```

Comment: well, that worked! was missing the single quotes. Stupid mistake. Thanks